# How to open and makes query to sqlite database with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I'm trying to do a client-side database visualizer with JS. I have never used JavaScript for doing this type of stuff, so I searched online and I found out this [web page](https://mydaytodo.com/reading-a-sqlite-database-using-client-side-javascript/). This is the script that I have done.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function handleFiles(files)
            {
                var file = files[0];
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
                openSqliteDb(reader);
            }
            
            function openSqliteDb(reader)
            {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    if(reader.readyState == reader.DONE)
                    {
                        var database = SQL.open(bin2Array(reader.result));
                        document.write("2");
                        executeQuery("SELECT * FROM User", database);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        openSqliteDb(reader);
                    }
                }, 500);
            }
            
            function executeQuery(commands, database)
            {
                document.write("1");
                commands = commands.replace(/n/g, '; ');
                try {
                    var data = database.exec(commands);
                    document.write(data);
                    processData(data);
                } catch(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
            }
            
            function processData(data)
            {
                document.write("1");
                var colHeaders = [];
                var colMap = {};
                var tableContent = [];
                var tableHtml = [];
                tableHtml.push("<table border='1' cellspacing='2' cellpadding-'3'>");
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    tableContent.push("<tr>");
                    var dataElem = data[i];
                    if (dataElem instanceof Array) {
                        for (var j = 0; j < dataElem.length; j++) {
                            var element = dataElem[j];
                            if (element.column && !colMap[element.column]) {
                                colHeaders.push("<th>" + element.column + "</th>");
                                colMap[element.column] = colHeaders.length;
                                tableContent.push("<td>&nbsp;" + element.value + "</td>");
                            } else {
                                tableContent.push("<td>&nbsp;" + element.value + "</td>");
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (element.column && !colMap[element.column]) {
                            colHeaders.push(element.column);
                            colMap[element.column] = colHeaders.length;
                        }
                    }
                    tableContent.push("</tr>");
                }
                tableHtml.push(colHeaders.join(" "));
                tableHtml.push(tableContent.join(" "));
                tableHtml.push("</table>");
                document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = tableHtml.join(" ");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <input type="file" id="input" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">
    </body>
    </html>
```

I can't figure it out why it is not working, but I think that the problem is the line `var database = SQL.open(bin2Array(reader.result));` in the `openSqliteDb()` function. Can somebody help me?

Comment: *"I can't figure it out why it is not working, but I think that the problem is the line"* - What specific observations lead you to that conclusion?  Are you getting any errors on the browser's console?  When you debug, what specifically happens?

Comment: i don't use debug for JS, i'm not good on programming in javascript, i'm a beginner. i only know that it is the line where the program stops, since i put some `document.write()` statements

Comment: Then now is a great time to start learning and practicing some basic debugging for JavaScript.  Your browser's debugging tools are the place to start.  If there are any errors, those will be shown on the debugging console.  You can use the script debugger to step through the code line by line as it executes and observe exact runtime behaviors, etc.  Additionally, `document.write()` is the wrong tool.  Use `console.log()` to output debugging information to the browser's console.

Comment: I opened Firefox console and when I execute the script it print out the error "Unchecked lastError value: Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist."

Comment: Using chrome it print out "Uncaught ReferenceError: SQL is not defined". Is there a way for importing SQL or something?

Comment: Well, `SQL` isn't defined anywhere in the code.  The page to which you link also links to the library you're using, which has its own documentation: https://github.com/sql-js/sql.js  Your code doesn't appear to be loading or initializing anything in that library.  The page to which you link may be incomplete as a tutorial, there's likely more you need to do to get it working.  Perhaps the author links to a more complete example you can reference.